# how does Tornado.ioloop.IOloop.start function work

Tags: python, tornado

In Tornado.ioloop.IOloop.start there is only one line code:

```
raise NotImplementedError()
```

I want to know what happens after the following codes

```
app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class IOLoop(Configurable)` is not actually used. It's only a base class. Tornado will select a proper subclass of it as default `IOLoop`. There's the classmethod for doing that:

```
@classmethod
def configurable_default(cls):
    if hasattr(select, "epoll"):
        from tornado.platform.epoll import EPollIOLoop
        return EPollIOLoop
    if hasattr(select, "kqueue"):
        # Python 2.6+ on BSD or Mac
        from tornado.platform.kqueue import KQueueIOLoop
        return KQueueIOLoop
    from tornado.platform.select import SelectIOLoop
    return SelectIOLoop
```

The implementation detail is sort of trivial. First in `tornado.util` there is a `class Configurable(object)`. Simply speaking, it will use `configurable_default` to configure itself. As mentioned above, our `IOLoop` is a subclass of `Configurable` and use its own `configurable_default` to choose the proper IOLoop subclass which has a working implementation of `start` function and everything else.

On Linux, the `PollIOLoop.start` method is actually executed. Its implementation is here:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/ioloop.py#L705